# Not able to publish on staging

Tags: dxa, publishing, sdl-tridion, publishingfailed

I am not able to publish anything on staging, however publishing is working on live.

When I opened one of the failed transaction, following error is showing.

[image]

**Update**: I have restarted all the services several times especially the transport service.
Also here is the error logs which was last generated:
[image][image]

Comment: > _"Probably Discovery service is not up and running"_ < from the log. I presume you've confirmed the Disco Service *is* running - and that all references to it are correct?

Comment: Yes, I have.Also @Dylan..MarkSaunders please confirm if this could be happening if the publishing is working fine for live..as this is only on staging..are there any different setting for both?if yes..where could i possibly found it

Comment: @BhawnaJain, The initial error screenshot which you have posted looks like an issue on deployer side, based on your latest update cd_transport logs, seems not able to access your staging discovery service. In the CME server try to access to validate your staging discovery service and staging deployer services URLs are accessible, looks like the connection refused. could be firewall blocked, also ensure those services are accessible inside the installed server itself.

Comment: Regarding “please confirm if this could be happening if the publishing is working fine for live...” — confirmed. If all is well, Staging and Live are two separate CD Environment that can have completely different configurations.

Comment: The Stack Trace suggests that is not possible to connect to Discovery/Token Service. Is the Disovery Service URL for the Staging CD Environment properly configured in Topology Manager?

Answer (score 2):

It’s difficult to give an exact cause of the problem with the information you’ve given, but the error message suggests that it’s a configuration issue with the Deployer (or a Deployer customisation).

If it were me, then I’d start by comparing the **cd_storage_conf.xml** and **deployer-conf.xml** files from Staging and Live for any glaring omissions/errors.

You may also want to double check that .jar files for any customisations (custom storage extensions, etc.) are correct and are present in the lib folder. Again, maybe you could compare the files on Staging against those on Live.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try and restart the staging Deployer? If no changes were made and it simply stopped working then a restart can help sometimes.

Also, in addition to Jonathan's proposal, you may want to check the logs of the deployer (cd_core and cd_deployer), usually there is a more detailed information about the error.

Answer (score 1):

I would ask that you check the following:

- Check Java, both that it is installed and that its path is public for your deployer to find (environment variables)
- Check your cd_licenses.xml, do you have it? is the location in the cd_storage_config.xml of the deployer correct? or for testing purposes can you put it in the config folder of the deployer?

However all this becomes irrelevant if you check the logs and it points to another issue.